# Error while fetching IP Address for SSH to Cisco Routers

Tags: python, ssh

I am trying to execute set of commands on a list of Cisco devices via ssh; while doing so, am getting the following error

> "gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed".

`Fetch.txt` is a text file where the IP Address of the devices are mentioned one by one.

```
import paramiko
import sys
import os
import select
import subprocess

with open('fetch.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:

        print line
        dssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        dssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        dssh.connect(line, username='cisco', password='cisco')
        mystring = stdout.read()
        print mystring
        f = open('output.txt', 'a+')
        f.write(mystring)
        f.close()

dssh.close()
```

Fetch.txt file looks like this,

```
    10.0.0.1
    10.0.0.2
    10.0.0.3
    10.0.0.4
    10.0.0.5
    10.0.0.6
    10.0.0.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating the file, `line` contains a trailing newline. That could be one of the reasons that cause `gaierror..` exception.

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.create_connection(('www.stackoverflow.com', 80)) # without newline
<socket._socketobject object at 0x0000000002C1B180>
>>> socket.create_connection(('www.stackoverflow.com\n', 80)) # with newline
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

Remove the trailing newline using [`str.strip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.strip) before pass it to the `paramiko.SSHClient.connect`:

```
...
for line in f:
    line = line.strip() # <---
    print line
    ...
```